# How does magento2 get category ID

Tags: magento2

I am a beginner. Could you please tell me how to get the current category ID on the magento2 category page? I want to show a specific banner in a specified category[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get current categoryId in your Block code like below:

```
  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    array $data = []
)
 public function getCurrentCategory()
{        
    return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
}
```

And you can use it in block like

> $category=$block->getCurrentCategory(); and $categoryId=$category->getId();

Answer (score 0):

Please Try below code to get category ID

```
<?php 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $category = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Registry::class)->registry('current_category');//get current category
    echo $category->getId();
    echo $category->getName();
?>
```

I hope it will help you

Comment: This code is fine for a test but should not be deployed in production.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default Magento block too.

Use `Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View` in your layout file as given below.

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="home.slider" template="Vendor_Module::homeslider.phtml" />
```

Now you can get the current category in your `homeslider.phtml` as shown below.

```
$current_category = $block->getCurrentCategory();
```